# Commas in 'Subaddress' of Hyperlink in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, hyperlink, worksheet

I tried referring to a worksheet which has a 'comma' in its label for the 'Subadresss' property of the Hyperlink object in VBA Excel.

Any idea how to get around this, rather than replacing the comma with other symbols?

Example:
My worksheet's name is : 1,1a

Here is the code for the hyperlink:

```
Worksheets("Worksheet1")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("c46"), _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="1,1a!A1"
```

On clicking on such a hyperlink, I will get a 'Reference is not valid' error.

Comment: @matzone hey. i added an example. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The sheet name needs to be inside inverted commas:

```
SubAddress:="'1,1a'!A1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer to this, but I did some testing, and assuming the workbook containing sheet 1,1a is named 'Workbook1.xlsx', this code should accomplish this:

```
With Worksheets("Worksheet1")
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("c46"), _
    Address:="Workbook1.xlsx", _
    SubAddress:="'1,1a'!A1"
End With
```

These pieces of knowledge seemed significant:

1. The spreadsheet name **must** be in the Address property
2. A worksheet name with spaces or punctuation must be surrounded by **single quotes**.

See the [HYPERLINK function](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HP010342583&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL&Version=14&CTT=5&origin=HP010342670) documentation for more information.